# Lost the `wp_options` table: what's the best way to restore the site?

Tags: database

Due to some important hardware failure, the `wp_options` table of one of my WP sites became corrupted, but everything else is okay (WP files and other tables). Obviously the site does not work because of this, and I had no backups.

What would be the best way to repair this? How can I create a fresh `wp_options` table for my WP version?

Answer (score 7):

Uh oh, that's an important table. You might have lost a bunch of options, but you can still repair the database. WordPress allows a repair mode, which you can repair the database.

Open the `wp-config.php` file using FTP, and add this line before the `ABSPATH`:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );
```

now head over to :

```
http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php
```

Follow the steps to repair your broken database.

Comment: The tool is reporting "Failed to repair the wp_options table. Error: Table 'site.wp_options' doesn't exist". I dropped the table because selecting from it would make MariaDB crash, even with `innodb_force_recovery` set to 6. So should I install a new WordPress having the same version and copy its fresh `wp_options` table to my site's database?

Comment: Yes you could do that. Have you also tried creating an empty `wp_options` tab manually using phpmyadmin, and then running the repair mode?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not rebuild WP_OPTIONS.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca I assume that table is built while installing WordPress. Many of its options are added by plugins, themes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your last suggestion (question?) is the right way to go, especially since you've already dropped that table.

Install a fresh version of WP into a new database (same version as your existing site), the export that table only from the new install and import it into your existing database.

Then BE SURE to set the two options that are critical, which is the blog URL and home URL, while you're still in phpMyAdmin, all other options can be set via the /wp-admin/ back-end when you can access it.